# HTML Button tag css

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to change the background colour and position of the first button from left to right so that the second button displays first. But the `:first-child` selector doesn't work.

I am using sass.

HTML structure-

```
<div class="buttonWrapper">
   <button class="reject" id="rcc-decline-button" aria-label="Decline cookies">Reject</button>
   <button class="accept" id="rcc-confirm-button" aria-label="Accept cookies">Accept Cookies</button>
</div>
```

My code:

```
.buttonWrapper button{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color:#000;
  button:first-child{
    background-color:#fff;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using sass? This is looking for `.buttonWrapper button button:first-child`

Comment: @Phix Yes I am using sass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a preprocessor (SASS, LESS, et al) which supports nesting, you should use the `&` selector inside the nesting:

```
.buttonWrapper button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;

  &:first-child{
    background-color: #fff;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
}
```

CSS by itself doesn't support nesting the way that preprocessors do. Regular CSS requires a more verbose syntax (Note: the above nested syntax will compile to this plain CSS):

```
.buttonWrapper button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.buttonWrapper button:first-child{
  background-color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```